# StructureMap Question

Tags: structuremap

**This is the equivalent of what I'm trying to create with StructureMap:**

```
new ChangePasswordWithNotificationAndLoggingService(
new ChangePasswordService(
      new ActiveDirectoryRepository(new ActiveDirectoryCredentials()),
      new TokenRepository("")),
new EmailNotificationService(new PasswordChangedNotification(new UserAccount())),
new LoggingService());
```

**This is what I have right now:**

```
ForRequestedType<IChangePasswordService>()
  .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(() => 
     new ChangePasswordService(DependencyRegistrar.Resolve<IActiveDirectoryRepository>(),
                               DependencyRegistrar.Resolve<ITokenRepository>()))
  .EnrichWith<IChangePasswordService>(x => 
     new ChangePasswordWithNotificationAndLoggingService(x,
                   DependencyRegistrar.Resolve<INotificationService>(),
                   DependencyRegistrar.Resolve<ILoggingService>()));
```

I need to pass the UserAccount to the INotificationService...can't figure it out.

**I've tried this:** 
DependencyRegistrar.With(new UserAccount { Username = "test" });

No luck...UserAccount always turns out null. I don't have to do it all with StructureMap, I'm open to any suggestions.

This is what I currently have working:

```
public static IChangePasswordService ChangePasswordService(UserAccount userAccount)
{
    return new ChangePasswordWithNotificationService(
        new ChangePasswordService(ActiveDirectoryRepository(), TokenRepository()),
        new EmailNotificationService(new PasswordChangedNotification(userAccount)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using [AutoWiring](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/07/autowiring-in-structuremap-2-5.aspx)? These are all concrete classes with simple construction so StructureMap can figure out what you need.

```
For<IChangePasswordService>().Use<ChangePasswordService>();
```

Looking at your construction I think that this simple configuration might just work.

**Edit**
Regarding the comments.

You should use the [With(T instance) method](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/01/23/some-new-ways-to-build-objects-in-structuremap-with-less-configuration.aspx) to have the container construct your IChangePasswordService using the given userAccount.

```
var userAccount = new UserAccount("derans"); 
var changePasswordService = container.With(userAccount).GetInstance<IChangePasswordService>();
```

Comment: I don't think it'll work because I need to be able to pass in the UserAccount object to the PasswordChangedNotification. It's not clear the way I showed the end-result at the top, but the new UserAccount() needs to be passed in to create the IChangePasswordService.

Right now I have it working, but not using StructureMap for everything...I'll edit the top to reflect what I actually am using currently to get the job done.

Comment: At retrieval time (not registration time), you can do:
Container.With(new UserAccount{Username = "test"}).GetInstance<IChangePasswordService>();

Comment: I've tried that one too, but with the current configuration of the IChangePasswordService in the registry, it doesn't work. UserAccount is always the default instance of UserAccount.

Answer (score 0):

Why not encapsulate the creation of the change password service into a factory - the factory is then an implemented as StructureMap factory that use a UserAccount passed in and the 'ObjectFactory' to create instances of the IIChangePasswordService as required?

I have demo'ed it below:

```
namespace SMTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // bootstrapper...
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry(new TestRegistry()));

        // create factory for use later (IoC manages this)...
        var changePasswordServiceFactory = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IChangePasswordServiceFactory>();

        var daveAccount = new UserAccount("Dave Cox");
        var steveAccount = new UserAccount("Steve Jones");

        var passwordService1 = changePasswordServiceFactory.CreateForUserAccount(daveAccount);
        var passwordService2 = changePasswordServiceFactory.CreateForUserAccount(steveAccount);


    }
}

public class TestRegistry : Registry
{
    public TestRegistry()
    {
        Scan(x =>
                 {
                     x.TheCallingAssembly();
                     x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IChangePasswordService));
                     x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IActiveDirectoryRepository));
                     x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IActiveDirectoryCredentials));
                     x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(ITokenRepository));
                     x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(INotification));
                     x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(INotificationService));
                     x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(ILoggingService));

                     ForRequestedType<ILoggingService>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MyLogger>();

                     ForRequestedType<IActiveDirectoryRepository>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MyAdRepository>();
                     ForRequestedType<IActiveDirectoryCredentials>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MyAdCredentials>();

                     ForRequestedType<ITokenRepository>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MyTokenRepository>();

                     ForRequestedType<IChangePasswordService>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<ChangePasswordService>();
                     ForRequestedType<IChangePasswordServiceFactory>().CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton).TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<StructureMapChangePasswordServiceFactory>();

                     ForRequestedType<INotification>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MyPasswordChangedNotification>();
                     ForRequestedType<INotificationService>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MyEmailNotificationService>();
                 });
    }
}

public interface ILoggingService
{
}

public class MyLogger : ILoggingService
{
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public UserAccount(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public interface INotification
{
}

public class MyPasswordChangedNotification : INotification
{
    private readonly UserAccount _account;
    private readonly ILoggingService _logger;

    public MyPasswordChangedNotification(UserAccount account, ILoggingService logger)
    {
        _account = account;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public interface INotificationService
{
}

public class MyEmailNotificationService : INotificationService
{
    private readonly INotification _notification;
    private readonly ILoggingService _logger;

    public MyEmailNotificationService(INotification notification, ILoggingService logger)
    {
        _notification = notification;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public interface ITokenRepository
{
}

public class MyTokenRepository : ITokenRepository
{
}

public interface IActiveDirectoryRepository
{
}

public interface IActiveDirectoryCredentials
{
}

public class MyAdCredentials : IActiveDirectoryCredentials
{
}

public class MyAdRepository : IActiveDirectoryRepository
{
    private readonly IActiveDirectoryCredentials _credentials;

    public MyAdRepository(IActiveDirectoryCredentials credentials)
    {
        _credentials = credentials;
    }
}

public interface IChangePasswordService
{
}

public class ChangePasswordService : IChangePasswordService
{
    private readonly IActiveDirectoryRepository _adRepository;
    private readonly ITokenRepository _tokenRepository;
    private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;

    public ChangePasswordService(IActiveDirectoryRepository adRepository, ITokenRepository tokenRepository, INotificationService notificationService)
    {
        _adRepository = adRepository;
        _tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
        _notificationService = notificationService;
    }
}

public interface IChangePasswordServiceFactory
{
    IChangePasswordService CreateForUserAccount(UserAccount account);
}

public class StructureMapChangePasswordServiceFactory : IChangePasswordServiceFactory
{
    public IChangePasswordService CreateForUserAccount(UserAccount account)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.With(account).GetInstance < IChangePasswordService>();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I feel like this is definitely on the right track, but it is missing the decorated ChangePasswordService. I think I might be able to figure it out from this code though. I'll give it a whirl. Thanks!